# How to modify a list of numbers in Python, preserving their order

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm trying apply an increase of 15 percent to items on list under 1000, and 12 percent to items equal or over 1000 on the same list. However, I've been able to do it by separating them into different lists. I'd like to retain the original list order and print the result.

Thanks in advance!
This is what I got thus far:

```
gross_list = [1350.50, 1240.25, 987.45, 1017.27, 870.9, 990.5]

print("Gross income list: " + str(gross_list))

fifteen_per = [i for i in gross_list if i < 1000]
fifteen_per = [(i * 0.15) + i for i in fifteen_per]

twelve_per = [i for i in gross_list if i >= 1000]
twelve_per = [(i * 0.12) + i for i in twelve_per]

print("Settlement: " + str(fifteen_per) + str(twelve_per))

payroll = sum(twelve_per + fifteen_per)
print("Payroll: " + str(format(payroll, ".2f")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for the task:

```py
gross_list = [1350.50, 1240.25, 987.45, 1017.27, 870.9, 990.5]

gross_list = [value * 1.15 if value < 1000 else value * 1.12 for value in gross_list]
print(gross_list)
```

Prints:

```
[1512.5600000000002, 1389.0800000000002, 1135.5674999999999, 1139.3424, 1001.5349999999999, 1139.0749999999998]
```

---

To get results as formatted strings:

```py
gross_list = [f'{value * 1.15 if value < 1000 else value * 1.12:.2f}' for value in gross_list]
print(gross_list)
```

Prints:

```
['1512.56', '1389.08', '1135.57', '1139.34', '1001.53', '1139.07']
```

Comment: In your ternary expression, you can avoid repeating `value` once if you use parentheses: `value * (1.15 if value < 1000 else 1.12)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single comprehension to perform both types of calculation in one pass.  Use the condition as an index to pick which factor to apply (False is zero, True is 1):

```
gross_list = [1350.50, 1240.25, 987.45, 1017.27, 870.9, 990.5]

payroll = [ round(i*(1.15,1.12)[i>=1000],2) for i in gross_list ]

[1512.56, 1389.08, 1135.57, 1139.34, 1001.53, 1139.07]
```